# Recasting Func to Specific Delegate

Tags: c#, nlog

I am making use of NLog's ability to take delegates instead of string as part of the call to log. For instance

```
log.Error(()=>"I am an error which was encountered at " + DateTime.Now)
```

This delegate is only evaluated if logging is enabled.  In theory it allows for faster execution as the delegate isn't always evaluated. Nifty.

My problems start when I wrap the NLog logger like a good 3rd party library consumer. I have an interface like

```
public interface ILog
{
 ...        
    void Error(string errorMessage, params string[] args);
    void Error(Func<string> messageGenerator);
    void Error(Exception excepetion, string errorMessage, params string[] args);
    void Error(Exception excepetion, Func<string> messageGenerator);
 ...
}
```

Then an implementation like

```
...

    public void Error(Func<string> messageGenerator)
    {
        //_log is an NLog logger
        _log.Error((LogMessageGenerator) messageGenerator);
    }
....
```

My problem is that in my error logs the lambdas are not being evaluated. I played around a bit and I believe that the issue is that when the Func is first created it is created as simply a Func and then when it is passed into NLog it is passed in as just that instead of a LogMessageGenerator. The NLog overload which accepts an object is called. So I'm guessing that when it is compiling lambdas the C# compiler attempts to statically type their return based on the context.

```
 //log is raw nlog logger
 log.Error(()=> "I am a terrible error"); => LogMessageGenerator
 //log is my wrapper
 log.Error(()=> "I am an even more terrible error"); => Func<string>
```

Is there any way to build my ILog implementation such that it still calls the correct overload of NLog without taking an explicit dependency on NLog in my interface by changing the method signature to take a LogMessageGenerator? I naively tried casting my Func into a LogMessageDelegate but that's a no go.

Comment: Why not just _log.Error(messageGenerator()); ?

Comment: @HansPassant, because if you do that, the delegate is always evaluated, even when logging is disabled. It defeats the purpose of using a delegate in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
public void Error(Func<string> messageGenerator)
{
    //_log is an NLog logger
    _log.Error(new LogMessageGenerator(messageGenerator));
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that produces the same output: it just logs the delegate and doesn't evaluate it.  I get 

2013-08-14 19:45:50.0826|ERROR|LoggerName|System.Func`1[System.String]

Comment: I find that very surprising. What do you see if you mouse over the call to _log.Error? What overload is it calling?

Comment: I gave that another try and indeed it did work. (I tried it on a different method which wasn't being called). Interestingly enough coderush flags it as a redundant delegate creation, although that sure isn't true.